# How to write a form that catches all errors?

Tags: c#

I want to write a form in my Windows Application Solution that catches whenever any exception is raised. Instead of showing that ugly error page, I want it to show the user a page that I've defined. How might I go about this?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Have a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms157905(v=vs.110).aspx But this will only catch Unhandled Exceptions in your code. An Unhandled Exception is the worst thing that could happen to your application, as it usually terminates it (crash). Please try handling possible exceptions in a `try catch finally` block

Comment: Do you have a general understanding of how error handling works in C#?

Comment: Do you know how to [catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtd0s8kd(v=vs.110).aspx) exceptions (errors) in C#? You can add your own code in the `catch` block to do whatever you like, including displaying the exception message however you like. What sort of application are you creating? Are you using WinForms, Windows Store, WPF..?

Comment: What if your “sth beatifully designed” throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that the below is not a replacement for a `try .. catch` logic in sensetive areas of your application. The below is not an advise to stop using `try ... catch`. The below is just a way to handle an unexpected exception and show some useful message (and maybe send an email to the support with stackTrace) before the application shuts down instead of an ugly windows message (Application XYZ stopped working).

You need to register for handling all unhandled exceptions (Except those on timers and secondary threads). `Program.cs` is a good place :

```
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);


    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    ShowCustomException(e.Exception);
}

private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    ShowCustomException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
}

private static void ShowCustomException(Exception ex)
{
    // show your custom exception form
}
```

Comment: It might be valuable to mention - this may be counterproductive when you're still developing the application. If exceptions are happening during the normal use of the application, this is not an effective solution. Instead, wrap potentially error-prone segments of code in `try..catch` blocks.